# Checking if semver if correct

Tags: node.js, package.json, semantic-versioning

I have dependencies in package.json like so:

```
<packageName1>: ^0.1.0,
<packageName2>: <url>,
<packageName3>: 5.1.0
```

Is there any way to check that "^0.1.0" and "5.1.0" are correct, but  "< url >" is incorrect semver?

I used semver npm package but haven't seen any functionality to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used semver.validRange method instead of semver.valid

Answer (score 0):

When referencing package by its url, you cannot specify any version; even if you do so, `npm` will ignore this.

Of course, you can do this manually: it's easy to read your `package.json`, parse out the `semver` constraint, get the version of your dependency (by reading its `package.json`) and finally using `node-semver` lib (or similar) to ensure, that the installed version is within range specified.

Comment: Thank you. I used semver.valid("^0.1.0") and get null. My soultion was semver.validRange